# High resolution monitor causes View text to be blurred in MFC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, plot

I am trying to plot signals on screen in real-time in my application, which is written in C++ using MFC framework.

I label the X and Y axis of my plots, also I have annotations along the axes. My plots looked fine when I was using a 1920*1080p monitor, since they were designed for that size. I used to write to a memory DC with clipBox of size 1920*1080 and simply BitBlt the drawing in the end after I had finished drawing on memory DC (double buffering technique).
But now that I have moved to 2560*1440p monitor, I use stretchBlt instead of BitBlt to fit the same old 1920*1080 clipBox in the new larger 2560*1440p frame. That causes my text for annotations and labels to be blurred.

What can I do to solve this problem? Can changing font or thickness of the letters help?

Comment: Create a bitmap the size of your canvas and just do bitblts.  If you try to "stretch" your graphics, you will always get blurry lines/text (it's hard to scale a pixel across 1.5 pixels)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this can be found in signal theory, this is actually not trivial at all.

Here is a reading:
http://www.number-none.com/product/Mipmapping,%20Part%201/index.html
http://www.number-none.com/product/Mipmapping,%20Part%202/index.html

So you understand, the problem comes from the kernel, it means that the `stretch` algorithm is using a bunch of neighbors and empirically weight them to compute an average for the current destination pixel. This average is effectively blurring your image.

To fix this problem you have only once choice : use the exact same original buffer (your clipBox as you say) size than the screen you blit to, and use pixel perfect copy.

OR, you could use the exact same size divided by exactly 2 on both dimensions, and use nearest filtering (kernel that does NOT average) when up scaling.

Answer (score 1):

Try using true type fonts, prepare the bitmap without text in the memory DC and StretchBlt it (if you have to), then use TextOut in the view's device context so that it can be optimized for the actual screen resolution. I would even tend to change the memory DC to the acutlal view's/screen's resulution to produce the optimal result. If you really have to provide memory DC with a standard size, use a much higher resultion, because interpolating pixels works better than extrapolating.